# GridViewColumn with ComboBox and UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, combobox

I have a GridViewColumn with Combobox BAsed on ComboBox selected I want to dynamically put UI elements.Below given is the code.OperatorList has three values "Between","After","Before".Based on this selection the template has to be loaded.If "Between" Multiple TextBox else Single textbox.This part works fine.But to get the content of this and store in Model Class for each row is where i am encountering problem.

```
<StackPanel>
     <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OperatorList}"  IsEditable="True"
                                          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                                          SelectedValue="{Binding ReferenceOperatorSelected}"  />
                                                    <UserControl x:Name="MyControl">

                                                    </UserControl>

                                                </StackPanel>
                                                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ReferenceOperatorSelected}" Value="Between">
                                                        <Setter TargetName="MyControl" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource MultipleTextBoxTemplate}"></Setter>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ReferenceOperatorSelected}" Value="After">
                                                        <Setter TargetName="MyControl" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SingleTextBoxTemplate}"></Setter>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ReferenceOperatorSelected}" Value="Before">
                                                        <Setter TargetName="MyControl" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SingleTextBoxTemplate}"></Setter>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </DataTemplate.Triggers>




    <DataTemplate x:Key="MultipleTextBoxTemplate">

                                    <StackPanel>

                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=BetweenValue1,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" MinWidth="40"></TextBox>
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=BetweenValue2,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="40"></TextBox>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
```

In my Model class I have two properties BetweenValue1 and BetweenVAlue2 ...These are not updated when i key in value in textboxes..

Comment: BetweenValue1 and BetweenVAlue2 are on your model or viewmodel? and the stackpanel containing combo and usercontrol is your gridview column template?

Comment: BetweenValue1 and BetweenValue2 are to be tracked in Model...Yes StackPanel and usercontrol are part of gridview column template..

Comment: so OperatorList,ReferenceOperatorSelected are all properties on your model?

Comment: Yes they are properties in my Model

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the Content for your UserControl. just try doing

```
<UserControl x:Name="MyControl" Content="{Binding}"/>
```